# Why is the [md-80] tag being changed to [dc-9-family]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Here:

- https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/64358/revisions
- https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/67396/revisions

Those actions were taken today. I don't know if others were done in the past, as part of a larger rename effort (and that's the issue: not knowing).

Those two questions are about the MD-80. If the ultimate goal is erasing [md-80](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/md-80) in favor of [dc-9-family](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-9-family), I think it needs to go through a discussion here first via a request for synonyms to the [dc-9-family](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-9-family).

Community consensus will help with future tags. For example, if someone tags [boeing-717](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boeing-717), should it automatically change to [dc-9-family](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-9-family), or will this manual rename effort continue in the background without consensus?

To streamline the process:

► Should MD-80/-90 and Boeing 717 be synonyms to the [dc-9-family](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-9-family) or not, and why?

Note that in @fooot's answer to [Were the MD-90 and 717 ever known by DC-9-9x names](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3953/14897) the following was proposed:

> I think we should at least have separate tags for them.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use [dc-9-family](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-9-family) to refer to either the models marketed as DC-9's or something that asks about the larger family. Although the [md-80](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/md-80) is a bit closer to the DC-9 heritage, I think the existing questions are specific enough to that model and tagging it as such is more likely to be understood.